# Duda con DateTime

Tags: php

tengo una aplicación donde el empleado puede hacer solicitudes de vacaciones. Bien mi problema viene cuando yo quiero elegir fechas atrasadas. Me explico mejor, tengo este `if`:

```
if($fecha_inicio < $fecha_solicitud){
    echo "Start date can not be less than today's date";
}
```

Este `if` dice que si la fecha en la que quiere iniciar las vacaciones es menor que la fecha de la solicitud(hoy), que salte un error.

Cada fecha es del tipo `DateTime`. Con este `if` me hace perfecto que no puedan coger días atrasado. El problema viene con la hora, por ejemplo:

Si cuando el usuario hace la solicitud son 12:00 del día de hoy, y el usuario, porque esté enfermo se coge el día de hoy de vacaciones. El usuario debe cogerse el día de hoy desde las 8:00 de la mañana. Ahí es cuando me dá el error, al ser menor la hora y no quiero que me tenga en cuenta la hora, solo el día. Alguna ayuda??

Comment: Puedes probar dándole formato a la fecha `date("Y-m-d",strtotime($fecha_inicio))` y lo mismo para el otro parámetro `date("Y-m-d",strtotime($fecha_solicitud))`

Comment: Se me ocurre que debes convertir la fecha a un formato `Y-m-d`  o `d-m-Y` para que no te tome en cuenta las horas.

Comment: @J.Rodríguez Muchas gracias! Me ha sido de gran ayuda!

Comment: @WalterCordova Muchas gracias! Me ha sido de gran ayuda!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Intenta con esto:

```
if($fecha_inicio < $fecha_solicitud &&
   $fecha_inicio->format('d-m-Y') !== $fecha_solicitud->format('d-m-Y')){
     echo "End date can not be less than start date";
}
```

Así solo va a saltar el error si fecha_inicio es menor a la fecha de solicitud y son de dias diferentes, por tanto el tema de la hora ya no importa

Comment: Muchas gracias! Me ha sido de gran ayuda!

Comment: De nada este sitio es para eso :P

Answer (score 0):

Tú puedes comparar los objetos `DateTime` basándote en un formato en el cual no se tome en cuenta la hora.

Veamos esta función, que recibe dos objetos a comparar. A ambos objetos le aplica `format('Y-m-d')` y luego se puede comparar.

En mi opinión, no deberías comparar solamente usando el operador `<`, sino que deberías poner `<=`.

```
function compararFechas($fechaInicio,$fechaSolicitud){
    if ( $fechaInicio->format('Y-m-d') <= $fechaSolicitud->format('Y-m-d')){
        echo "Start date: ".$fechaInicio->format('Y-m-d') ." can not be less or equal than today's date: ".$fechaSolicitud->format('Y-m-d').PHP_EOL;
    }else{
        echo "You can apply for vacations starting at: ".$fechaInicio->format('Y-m-d')."!".PHP_EOL;
    }
}
```

---

### Prueba del código

**<kbd>[VER DEMO EN REXTESTER](http://rextester.com/NCDU13563)</kbd>**

Vamos a hacer varias pruebas de nuestra función:

```
$fechaSolicitud = new DateTime('now');

/*Prueba 1*/
$fechaInicio = new DateTime('2018-03-15 16:20:07.900');
compararFechas($fechaInicio,$fechaSolicitud);


/*Prueba 2*/
$fechaInicio = new DateTime('2018-03-14 10:20:07.900');
compararFechas($fechaInicio,$fechaSolicitud);

/*Prueba 3*/
$fechaInicio = new DateTime('2018-03-14 17:50:07.900');
compararFechas($fechaInicio,$fechaSolicitud);

/*Prueba 4*/
$fechaInicio = new DateTime('2011-03-14 17:50:07.900');
compararFechas($fechaInicio,$fechaSolicitud);
```

Esta sería la salida para las cuatro pruebas:

```
You can apply for vacations starting at: 2018-03-15!
Start date: 2018-03-14 can not be less or equal than today's date: 2018-03-14
Start date: 2018-03-14 can not be less or equal than today's date: 2018-03-14
Start date: 2011-03-14 can not be less or equal than today's date: 2018-03-14
```